# Are gentiles accepted as witnesses by a Beis Din in civil law arbitrations?

Tags: gentiles, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, edim-witnesses

I assume a gentile is not kosher to give eidus in general, (women, minors etc excluded - kal vekhomer gentiles..) although I may be mistaken.

But in a civil case brought before a beis din for arbitration, seems likely that frequently testimony from involved gentile parties would be relevant. How is that dealt with?

Comment: Perhaps מסיח לפי תומו is accepted but I’m not sure

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mark and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!